# Dynamically name list elements from function argument

Tags: r, list, function, parameter-passing, naming

**I'm trying to dynamically name list elements within a function from a given argument:**

This works with static names (non-function):

```
list(comp1 =
         c("setosa" = 1,
           "versicolor" = 0,
           "virginica" = -1))

$comp1
group1 group2 group3 
     1      0     -1
```

But when I want to feed a string (`"group1"`, etc.) from group names (e.g., `cyl` from the `mtcars` dataset) that would usually come from a function:

```
list(comp1 =
         c(levels(iris$Species)[1] = 1,
           levels(iris$Species)[2] = 0,
           levels(iris$Species)[3] = -1))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"list(comp1 =
         c(levels(iris$Species)[1] ="
Error: unexpected ',' in "           levels(iris$Species)[2] = 0,"
Error: unexpected ')' in "           levels(iris$Species)[3] = -1)"
```

Yet the output should be the same:

```
> levels(iris$Species)[1]
[1] "setosa"
> levels(iris$Species)[2]
[1] "versicolor"
> levels(iris$Species)[3]
[1] "virginica"
```

**Question: Is there any way to name these list elements from the given function argument (e.g., group names)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setNames` to assign the names.

```
list(comp1 = setNames(c(1, 0, -1), levels(iris$Species)))

#$comp1
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#         1          0         -1
```

Comment: Whoa! I'm mind blown! I've spent so much time on this! And it works with my full function/data too!  Didn't know this function. Had tried `as.name`.